# Easiest way to transfer data between 2 C programs?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, ipc, process

In ANSI C on Windows what is the best/easiest way to transfer data between two programs running locally without needing to write/read from a file? Data will be basic text and only one program will be sending and the other receiving. Thanks.

Comment: two programs (processes) and two threads are completely different sets of beasts. which do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inter-process communication is inherently platform-dependent; "ANSI C" doesn't have anything to say about this, but you should start here for Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx

Much depends on the kinds of applications you're talking about, and the volume of data, and how tightly coupled the processes are.